# How can I achive this behavor in nginx

Tags: nginx

What is the configuration needed in Nginx to achieve the following behavior:

Whenever a request is received, it should be forwarded to application A; if application A returns { "allowed" :true} in response, the same request should be forwarded to application B and the response from application B should be returned to the client. However, if application A returns a { "allowed" : false} in response, the server should return a response with a status code of 401.

Something like this:

```
server {
   listen  80;

location / {
    # forword request to App-A;
    proxy_pass https://app-A.dev/;
    # Read the response
    if response['allowed'] == true;
        # forword it to application B
        proxy_pass https://app-B.dev/;
    else:
        return '401';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nginx does not support conditional directives. You could possibly use the `ngx_lua` plugin to achieve something similar, though.

Comment: Nginx can do this with auth subrequests: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Comment: @NickODell, that is a module, similar to `ngx_lua`, nginx out the box does not support   conditional directives.

Comment: @Gerhard The OP wants to conditionally fail requests which don't pass authentication. The module linked above can do that. The question doesn't say, "I want to avoid optional modules."

Comment: Yes @NickODell, but you state nginx can do it, it cannot, a module for nginx can do it.

Comment: @Gerhard any idea how can I do it with lua module?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this at all as I have not got a similar environment to yours, but the `lua` script should be something like:

```
http {
    lua_shared_dict allow_dict 1m;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://app-A.dev/;
            header_filter_by_lua_block {
                local allow = ngx.resp.get_headers()['allow']
                if allow == 'true' then
                    ngx.ctx.allow = true
                end
            }
            body_filter_by_lua_block {
                if ngx.ctx.allow then
                    ngx.var.proxy_pass = https://app-B.dev/
                end
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See nore about the module [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/)